# How to redirect to another page When i searched item in Auto TextBox

Tags: c#, angularjs

Here i wrote some code for Autocomplete Textbox its working fine but when i selected that name How can i Redirect to that page

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="Helloctrls">
    <div ng-cloak="" angucomplete-alt id="ex1_dropdown" input-class="form-control">

    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="ss in SerchDetails">
        <ul>
            @{
                var uri = Url.Action("{{ss.Action}}", "{{ss.Countrolle}}");

                uri = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri);


            }
        </ul>

                <a href="@uri">{{ss.Action}} </a>


    </div>
```